# Register,update user information and send data to two tables at the same time in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I need to register a new user and store data in two tables separately, the Users table will hold classic id /name / email / password information while the doctor table will hold different information related to the new registered user, for example gender, age, user_pic etc. I also need to edit the user info & save the value in two tables.How can I achieve this.Thanks.
My route file is

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth'
    ], function() {


        Route::get('/home', [
        'as' => 'admin',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
    ]);

        Route::get('/profile', array('as' =>'profile' ,'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'));

    //     Route::get('/profile/{profile_id}',[
    //     'as' => 'profile',
    //     'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'
    // ]);

        Route::get('/mail',[
        'as' => 'mail',
        'uses' => 'MailController@index'
    ]);

    });
```

My Doctor Model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doctor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'division_id',
        'district_id',
    ];

    public function district()
    {

        return $this->belongsto('App\District');
    }
    public function division()
    {

        return $this->belongsto('App\Division');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create a form and send POST method to this route : **user/save**

### Routes.php

```
Route::post('user/save', 'UserController@store')->name('addUser');
```

create a controller with **artisan**

```
php artisan make:comtroller UserController
```

### UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validate
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' = 'required',
            'email' = 'required|email',
            'gender' = 'required',
            'age' = 'required'
        ]);

        // save users table
        $user = new App\User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->save();

        // save doctor table
        DB::table('doctor')
        ->insert(
            'id'        =>  $user->id,
            'gender'    =>  $request->input('gender'),
            'age'       =>  $request->input('age')
        );  

        // set a flush message and redirect()->back();
        return TRUE;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I did not do it in route file. I want to do it in Controller File.How can I achieve this?